# How to convert Onnx model (.onnx) to Tensorflow (.pb) model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch

I am trying to convert .onxx model to .pb model. I have written the code but i am getting error:

> @tf_func(tf.ceil)AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'ceil'

Code:

```
import onnx
from tensorflow.python.tools.import_pb_to_tensorboard import import_to_tensorboard
from onnx_tf.backend import prepare
onnx_model = onnx.load("original_3dlm.onnx")
tf_rep = prepare(onnx_model)
tf_rep.export_graph("model_var.pb")
import_to_tensorboard("model_var.pb", "tb_log")
```

How to resolve this issue? Is there any other way to convert Onxx to Tensorflow?

Comment: If you are trying with `tf==1.x` then
Please use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71309830/13332582) answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solve this issue with this.
[Tensorflow Backend for ONNX](https://github.com/onnx/onnx-tensorflow).
Let me know if you have any issue.
Change from tensorflow 2.0 to 1.14.Maybe solve the problem.

Comment: I have already used command line interface it is throwing same error

Comment: what tensorflow use?2.0?Maybe change to 1.14 or 1.13.In TF 2.0 there are many changes.

Comment: perfect! great!

Answer (score 1):

your code as far as I can tell should be fine. The problem probably lies in the onnx-tf version you currently use. pip currently installs a version that only supports TensorFlow <= 1.15.
run this in the terminal to install a more up-to-date version of onnx-tf.

```
pip uninstall onnx_tf
pip install git+https://github.com/onnx/onnx-tensorflow.git
```

refer to [this issue](https://github.com/onnx/onnx-tensorflow/issues/454) for further details

Comment: how this is relevant to conversion. Please describe your solution properly

Comment: it should have already been clear but I made it clearer.