# How can we convert a .pth model into .pb file?

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch

I have already got the complete model by using pytorch, however I wanna convert the .pth file into .pb, which could be used in Tensorflow. Does anyone have some ideas?

Answer (score 12):

You can use [ONNX](https://onnx.ai/): Open Neural Network Exchange Format

To convert `.pth` file to `.pb` First, you need to export a model defined in PyTorch to ONNX and then import the ONNX model into Tensorflow (PyTorch => ONNX => Tensorflow)

This is an example of MNISTModel to [Convert a PyTorch model to Tensorflow using ONNX](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/onnx/tutorials/blob/master/tutorials/PytorchTensorflowMnist.ipynb#Save-the-trained-model) from [onnx/tutorials](https://github.com/onnx/tutorials/blob/master/tutorials/PytorchTensorflowMnist.ipynb)

#### Save the trained model to a file

```py
torch.save(model.state_dict(), 'output/mnist.pth')
```

#### Load the trained model from file

```py
trained_model = Net()
trained_model.load_state_dict(torch.load('output/mnist.pth'))

# Export the trained model to ONNX
dummy_input = Variable(torch.randn(1, 1, 28, 28)) # one black and white 28 x 28 picture will be the input to the model
torch.onnx.export(trained_model, dummy_input, "output/mnist.onnx")
```

#### Load the ONNX file

```py
model = onnx.load('output/mnist.onnx')

# Import the ONNX model to Tensorflow
tf_rep = prepare(model)
```

#### Save the Tensorflow model into a file

```py
tf_rep.export_graph('output/mnist.pb')
```

AS noted by [@tsveti_iko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4137497/tsveti-iko) in the comment

> NOTE: The `prepare()` is build-in in the `onnx-tf`, so you first need to install it through the console like this `pip install onnx-tf`, then import it in the code like this: `import onnx from onnx_tf.backend import prepare` and after that you can finally use it as described in the answer.

Comment: NOTE: The `prepare()` is build-in in the `onnx-tf`, so you first need to install it through the console like this `pip install onnx-tf`, then import it in the code like this: `import onnx` 
 `from onnx_tf.backend import prepare` and after that you can finally use it as described in the answer.

Comment: @tsveti_iko thanks to bring attention. i thought it should be in the answer rather in comment so i have added it in the answer.

Comment: indeed, you can even insert the code parts in your existing code blocks and remove the NOTE quote

Answer (score 0):

If you are using TF 1.15 or below you might not find above code helpful because you would end-up solving miss-match version error
So here is all version matched code working for TF 1.X

```
Keras                2.3.0
Keras-Applications   1.0.8
Keras-Preprocessing  1.1.2
numpy                1.21.5
onnx                 1.8.0
onnx-tf              1.3.0
protobuf             3.19.4
tensorboard          1.15.0
tensorflow           1.15.0
tensorflow-estimator 1.15.1
torch                1.6.0+cpu
torchvision          0.7.0+cpu
```

After having all these packages use the answer by [Dishin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6075699/dishin-h-goyani)

Note: `Variable` is depreciated in newer version of `torch`