# 'No schema registered' in ONNX model conversion

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js, onnx

I am using kaggle notebook. I am trying to convert my pytorch model into tensorflow model to run with tensorflowJS. I used below code to convert onnx model to tensorflow model-

```
import onnx
from onnx_tf.backend import prepare
 
onnx_model = onnx.load("../input/onnx-model/model.onnx")
tf_rep = prepare(onnx_model)
tf_rep.export_graph("output/model.pb")
```

I got

```
SchemaError: No schema registered for 'BitShift'!
```

I tried with onnx version 1.8.1 , 1.8.0 and then further downgrade to 1.6.0 .

Also, I tried to run onnx model directly with onnx.js but facing issue in image normalization and resizing. Hence, I decided to switch to tfjs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same issue. Uninstall the onnx-tf and run
`pip install git+https://github.com/onnx/onnx-tensorflow.git`. Issue seems to be with some exception type.

Comment: Yes..!! I got solution from github repo. Btw...thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested it for `tf-1.15.0`, and downgrading onnx by `pip install onnx==1.8.0`
For more details use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71309830/13332582) answer