# How to convert .pth file of LightGCN model to .pb file?

Tags: python, pytorch, gnn

I was trying to convert a `LightGCN` `.pth` file to a `pb` file, but I don't know how to convert it. I used the `onnx` lib, but I don't know the function of `dummy_input`, and am not sure that was correct.

```py
import onnx
from onnx_tf.backend import prepare
from torch.autograd import Variable

trained_model = Recmodel  # Recmodel is LightGCN model
trained_model.load_state_dict(torch.load(weight_file))

# Export the trained model to ONNX
dummy_input = Variable(torch.randn(1, 1, 28, 28)) # one black and white 28 x 28 picture will be the input to the model
torch.onnx.export(trained_model, dummy_input, "output/gnn.onnx")
```

And also I got an error:

```
TypeError: LightGCN.forward() missing 1 required positional argument: 'items'
```

I referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59450262/how-can-we-convert-a-pth-model-into-pb-file).

Comment: The purpose is to send deep learning model to server and only use it.